# How to cancel any/all work manager request if the app is removed directly from app tray?

Tags: android, android-service, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I'm trying to use Android WorkManager in an application in order to schedule some background task. The requirement is to cancel the API request when the app is removed directly from app-tray.

I'm able to detect if app is getting removed from app-tray, by using Service class -> onTaskRemoved method. And here I'm making the WorkManager API cancel request.

```
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    Log.d("onTaskRemoved","onTaskRemoved called");
    WorkManager.getInstance().cancelAllWork();
}
```

This is working fine as expected. Please suggest if there is any other better alternative to achieve it.

Comment: The @SumirKodes is the actual correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For some android devices (for some vendors)** they implemented like if any apps is removed from app tray means they will **force stop** the app.So the services,work manager are also stopped.

**For some other android devices (for some 
 other vendors)** they implemented like if any apps is removed from app tray means they will **stop/kill only the current activity of the app & not force stop the app**.So the services,work manager are not stopped.

First you need to check your target devices is comes in which category.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do this, I think you're probably using the wrong tool. WorkManager is specifically for requests that need to persist and execute at some point. Consider using an Executor or coroutine instead.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky It will go away and not re-execute upon app death, which is what the OP wanted.

Comment: You'd need a `lifecycleScope` or `viewModelScope` for that